# How to setup 'rhc' for openshift origin all-in-one

Tags: openshift-origin

When trying to run *rhc* setup, I get the following:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ rhc setup --debug --server localhost:8443 --insecure
DEBUG: Using config file /home/vagrant/.openshift/express.conf
DEBUG: Running greeting_stage
OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace, and check that other programs like Git are properly installed.
DEBUG: Running server_stage
DEBUG: Running login_stage
DEBUG: Connecting to https://localhost:8443/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
DEBUG: Created new httpclient
DEBUG: Request GET https://localhost:8443/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: SSL Verification failed -- Using self signed cert
DEBUG:    code 403   25 ms
```

Is there someway to run setup with the self-signed cert that comes with the origin all-in-one ?

Comment: Be aware that the command line client for current Origin all in one is ``oc``, not ``rhc``. The ``rhc`` client is for older OpenShift 2, not latest OpenShift 3. Perhaps read through to understand how to use latest Origin all in one VM the free eBook at https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html if you are really wanting OpenShift 3.

Comment: you're spot on.  regardless of the problems i'm encountering, i'm trying to solve the wrong problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Graham Dumpleton's comment, I am trying to solve the wrong problem.

> Be aware that the command line client for current Origin all in one is
>   oc, not rhc. The rhc client is for older OpenShift 2, not latest
>   OpenShift 3. Perhaps read through to understand how to use latest
>   Origin all in one VM the free eBook at
>   openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html if you are really wanting
>   OpenShift 3. – Graham Dumpleton Jan 2 at 23:20